# My manually built TYPO3 lightbox isn't working properly

Tags: typo3, colorbox, typo3-6.1.x

In a COA, I have this TypoScript to add an image linked to a larger copy of itself. But the Javascript plugin I'm using (Colorbox) isn't able to resize the image properly.

```
  20 = CONTENT
  20 {
    wrap = <div class="lightbox clearfix">|</div>
    required = 1

    table = tt_content
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    select.where = colPos = 2
    select.selectFields = bodytext,image,header
    renderObj=COA
    renderObj{   

      10 = FILES
      10 {
          required = 1
          references {
            table = tt_content
            fieldName = image
          }
          renderObj = IMAGE
          renderObj {
            file.import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
            file.width=300c
            file.height=300c
            imageLinkWrap = 1
            imageLinkWrap {
                enable = 1
                width = 1600m
                height = 1600m
                JSwindow = 0
                linkParams.ATagParams { 
                 // title.data = 
                  dataWrap = class = "lightbox-group" title="{file:current:description}"
                }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

What's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct TypoScript. I'm sharing it because it is a legacy weirdness others might stumble upon too.

You have to set `imageLinkWrap.directImageLink = 1`, else imageLinkWrap won't deliver the image itself, but a HTML page [containing that image](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/581)!

```
20 = CONTENT  
20 {
        wrap = <div class="lightbox clearfix">|</div>
        required = 1

        table = tt_content
        select.languageField = sys_language_uid
        select.where = colPos = 2
        select.selectFields = bodytext,image,header
        renderObj=COA
        renderObj{


          10 = FILES
          10 {
              required = 1
              references {
                table = tt_content
                fieldName = image
              }
              renderObj = IMAGE
              renderObj {
                file.import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
                file.width=300c
                file.height=300c
                imageLinkWrap = 1
                imageLinkWrap {
                    enable = 1
                    width = 1600m
                    height = 1600m
                    directImageLink = 1
                    JSwindow = 0
                    linkParams.ATagParams { 
                     // title.data = 
                      dataWrap = class = "lightbox-group" title="{file:current:description}"
                    }
                }
              }
          }
        }
      }
```